Best Snippers For Exposed Nail Tips
I had a company put a torch roof over my patio and the installer used some nails that were a little too long so I have (30) 1/4" long tips visible through the wood from my patio underneath, so I'd like to snip them off (won't look as good bent back). What's the best tool to do this? Hoping I can get a decent cutting tool to snip them off for not much money. Any help is very much appreciated!

angle grinder with diamond blade

How thick are the nails, and how flush (or recessed so you can plaster over them) do you want them?

Try some end nippers?

Thanks for the responses. I can't tell what size nails they are but they don't look very thick. I'm leaning toward nippers, I just hope it can snip 30. I forgot I have a small hacksaw that did a good job cutting back a much thicker toilet bolt last year so I think I'll give that a shot first. The trick will be trying to cut it as flush as I can.

The least expensive tool would probably be a rotary tool, like a Dremel, with a small cutoff wheel. They are light weight so that's a plus when working overhead and they will cut off the nails flush with the surface.

Warning: when working with rotary-tool ceramic cutoff wheels, eye protection is essential. The fiberglass ones don't cut as fast or thin but are less likely to disintegrate.

Rotary tools can be difficult to control.  If a power tool is used, something like an oscillating multitool with a metal-cutting blade might be easier to control, and the blade might be easier to get flush with the bottom of the deck too.
